Can Spring boot cloud gateway, RouteLocator url and serve some Rest API?
I have implemented a Gateway that route locates according to the URL path. I have app-related API that is incorporated in the Gateway application. when calling this API URL redirects his own instead of another URL.
like:
Gateway Application Url: /customer/** redirect to abc.org/customer?*
Gateway Application Url: /app/** redirect to his own RestController*
For /app/* There is a Restcontroller in the Gateway Application, which will work on its own.
return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
                .route("client-portal", r -> r.path("/api/**")
                        .and().method("POST", "GET")
                        .and()
                        .uri("http://localhost:9512"))
                .route("server-portal", r -> r.method("POST", "GET")
                        .and()
                        .uri("**Redirect Its own RestController**"))
                .build();


Donn't know is it right or wrong, but it works for me. set API gateway Url.
return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
            .route("client-portal", r -> r.path("/api/**")
                    .and().method("POST", "GET")
                    .and()
                    .uri("http://localhost:9512"))
            .route("host-portal", r -> r.path("/device/**")
                    .and().method("POST", "GET")
                    .and()
                    .uri("*Api Gateway Url*"))
            .build();


If your spring-cloud-gateway offers its own REST API in addition to routing to other backend services, you don’t need to provide routes in the RouteLocatorBuilder for those.
Just expose the API with a @RestController or with router functions (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-web)
